# Как разместить в latex степени функции слева, а не справа

Tags: javascript, математика, latex

Я использую библиотеку [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/) для генерации TeXа
Однако выражение `sin(x)^2` библиотека переводит в код: `{\sin\left( x\right)}^{2}`, который выглядит вот так:
[image: вывод]

Но мне нужно, чтобы это выглядело так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Могу ли я как-то это сделать преобразовав строку `{\sin\left( x\right)}^{2}`так, чтобы это выглядело как мне нужно? (синус тут для примера, вообще мне нужен тот формат, который выдаёт wolframalpha, т.е. чтобы степень была левее для синуса, косинуса, тангенса, логарифмов (`ln`, `log2`, `log`, `log10`) и т.п.).

Или же как-то настроить конвертацию в TeX в библиотеке mathjs?

Answer (score 0):

Так должно работать:

```latex
\sin^{2}\left(x\right)
```